# AFHTTPClient.h mysteriously wants to add @end before interface, but then rejects its own suggestion

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

This is driving me crazy! I even have a different project with the exact same h file that works fine yet this does not. Xcode keeps forcing me to have to put an @end (in bold) by putting it in red, then it rejects its own suggestion with the red error "@end must appear in objective c context". WHAT AM I DOING WRONG!!!!!!

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @class AFHTTPRequestOperation;
    @protocol AFHTTPClientOperation;
    @protocol AFMultipartFormData;


    #ifdef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H
    extern NSString * const AFNetworkingReachabilityDidChangeNotification;
    #endif

    #ifdef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H
    typedef enum {
        AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown          = -1,
        AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable     = 0,
        AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN = 1,
        AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi = 2,
    } AFNetworkReachabilityStatus;
    #endif


    typedef enum {
        AFFormURLParameterEncoding,
        AFJSONParameterEncoding,
        AFPropertyListParameterEncoding,
    } AFHTTPClientParameterEncoding;

    extern NSString * AFURLEncodedStringFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding);


    extern NSString * AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(NSDictionary *parameters, NSStringEncoding encoding);


    **@end** //Here it keeps trying to force me to place an @end, then gives the error "@end must appear in objective c context"
    @interface AFHTTPClient : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying>
...
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are missing and @end in a different .h file. So probably you have one file #importing the corrupted .h (missing @end) and then you #import this file. That would explain the error.